# informatica is taking the source file as the indirect file

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I had made a source file data type change in source analyzer. I did realize that it had made the mapping invalid. I ran the mapping and it failed. Now I reverted the change, validated the mapping, check in the mapping, validated the workflow, check in the workflow.
Now I am getting the error:

```
Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code Message
INFO 7/23/2015 10:40:03 AM node01_CSADevelopment READER_1_4_1 FR_3055 Reading input filenames from the indirect file [<input_directory_folder>/<input_file>].

Severity Timestamp Node Thread Message Code Message
ERROR 7/23/2015 10:40:03 AM node01_CSADevelopment READER_1_4_1 FR_3000 Error opening file [<input_file_folder>/<header_of_the_input_file>]. Operating system error message [No such file or directory].
```

here the term "input file" is the file which I wanted to load and "header_of_the_input_file" is the header of the input file.

I don't understand, why it is happening. I had just made a small change and then reverted it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is just saying the filenames mentioned in the indirect file are not found. So, you just need to make sure all the source files are there in the "input_file_folder"

There is a property in the session to configure the source file as indirect. An indirect file contains a list of source filenames. Informatica reads all the files listed and loads the data. If you think you have inadvertently made the source file indirect, you can change the option in session properties (mapping tab -> Source Qualifier)

It does not have anything to do with the datatype change and reverting it.